# "Never attempt to win by force what can be won by deception"

Tags: grammar

In this sentence, is it possible for 'what can be won by deception' to act as an adjective that modifies 'force'?

Comment: "what can" sounds very awkward. I'd use "that which can". It sits better in the 'wise old adage' category such phrases attempt to be counted among. This would then sit alongside such as [Hanlon's Razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanlon%27s_razor) "Never attribute to malice that which is adequately explained by stupidity."

Answer (score 1):

The expression "what can be won by deception" is a content clause (or noun clause).  Not a relative clause (not an adjective clause).

Compare your sentence with a sentence containing a noun instead of a content clause:

> Never try to win *a prize* by force.

Note that the content clause is delayed to the end of the sentence.

It would not be possible to parse this as a relative clause.  If you used "that", then it may be grammatically possible, but the resulting noun phrase "force that can be won by deception" is meaningless. (what would it mean if you "win a force"?)